# Laravel query models that are contained in a constant

Tags: php, laravel, search, eloquent

What i need to do is, basically, the reverse of a search in the DB.

I have a model, let's call it `Search` which contains all the searches users made on my website. Given a specific text, i need to know how many of those searches would match the text.

**Example** Given the searches `iphone`,`apple`, `samsung` and the text `apple iphone X 16gb`, the result would be 2, because `iphone` and `apple` are matched but `samsung` isn't.

What i tried is:

```
$searches = Search::select('id')
            ->where(DB::raw("'". $text ."' LIKE CONCAT('%', searched_text, '%')"))
            ->count();
```

But it always return 0, no matter what. There is a simple way of achieving this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, you have `iphone`, `apple` and `samsung` in DB and now you want to count by `apple iphone X 16gb` string.

If you want to use exact match, use `whereIn()`:

```
Search::whereIn('searched_text', explode(' ', $search))->count();
```

If you want to use `like`, for example if you want to also count `iphones` and not only `iphone`:

```
$words = explode(' ', $search);
$query = Search::query();
foreach ($words as $word) {
    $query = $query->orWhere('searched_text', 'like', '%' . $word . '$');
}
$counted = $query->count();
```

Comment: In this specific case it works, however i need it to work also for partial text and not exact words, ie 'phone' should match with 'apple iphone X 16gb' as well

Comment: @gbalduzzi it will match if you'll use the second code example.